# Clarification of a potential textbook contradiction: whether a spanning set generates a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I have the following set $S=\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ and I am asked when $\text{span}(S)=\mathbb{F}_p^3$, for a field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a prime.

**My work so far**: I have that any set of $n$-vectors spans a $n$-dimensional vector space of which it is a subset $\iff$ the vectors are linearly independent. Therefore, I assume that the latter vector is dependent on the first two and see what result arises for $p$. I write that $c(1,1,0)+d(1,0,1)=(0,1,1)$ for some $c,d\in \mathbb{F}_p$. This gives that $c+d\equiv 0 \mod{p}$ and also that $c,d\equiv 1 \mod{p}$ which only occurs when $c\equiv 1,p-1 \mod{p} \implies p=2$. I conclude that $\forall p\neq 2$,  $\text{span}(S)=\mathbb{F}_p^3$.

However, I read an exercise later on that reads "Show that the vectors $\{(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$ generate $\mathbb{F}^3$, for an arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$."

**My question**: Does this contradict my work? Have I erred in my proof?

Comment: Your work is correct. The claim in the later exercise is wrong. The set $\{(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1)\}$ is linearly dependent and does not generate $\Bbb{F}_2^3$.

Comment: Your work is right, in characteristic 2 (when 1+1=0) you can't span everything.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$ 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ $\rightarrow$
 $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$ using Gaussian elimination.

So the matrix with the vectors as columns is invertible for all $p \neq 2$, so they are independent and $3$ independent vectors in a $3$-dimensional space spaen that space. (for $p=2$ we have that the vectors are dependent as their sum is $0$).

How can this be a contradiction: first you show that the vectors span $\mathbb{F}_p^3$ when using a field of the form $\mathbb{F}_p$, and finally you have to show this in fact holds for all fields. But the statement is *false* for all fields of characteristic $2$, like $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$. In all other fields (those that don't have characteristic $2$), the pivots are $1$, $-1$ and $2$, all non-zero.

Comment: In the last sentence, "all other fields" should be "all other fields of the form $\mathbb F_p$" (which are the only fields involved in the question). The given vectors are dependent whenever the field has characteristic $2$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I reformulated the final part a bit. Thx.